# Locking mechanism on pNFS

Tags: linux, nfs, nfs4

As I know, in parallel NFS, after getting Layout from Meta Data Server, Client communicate directly with the Data Server. I wander what will happen if multi clients read or write to the same region of the Data Server simultaneously. Are there any machanism for locking in pNFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per RFC 5661 (nfs 4.1 incl. pnfs)
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5661#section-12.5.1

> The requirement of NFSv4.1 that all user access rights MUST be
> obtained through the appropriate OPEN, LOCK, and ACCESS operations is
> not modified with the existence of layouts.  Layouts are provided to
> NFSv4.1 clients, and user access still follows the rules of the
> protocol as if they did not exist.  It is a requirement that for a
> client to access a storage device, a layout must be held by the
> client.

And further down in the same section:

> Note, clients are still required to    perform the appropriate OPEN,
> LOCK, and ACCESS operations as    described above.  The degree to
> which it is possible for the client    to circumvent these operations
> and the consequences of doing so must    be clearly specified by the
> individual layout type specifications.    In addition, these
> specifications must be clear about the    requirements and
> non-requirements for the checking performed by the    server.
>
> In the presence of pNFS functionality, mandatory byte-range locks
> MUST behave as they would without pNFS.  Therefore, if mandatory file
> locks and layouts are provided simultaneously, the storage device
> MUST be able to enforce the mandatory byte-range locks.  For example,
> if one client obtains a mandatory byte-range lock and a second client
> accesses the storage device, the storage device MUST appropriately
> restrict I/O for the range of the mandatory byte-range lock.  If the
> storage device is incapable of providing this check in the presence
> of mandatory byte-range locks, then the metadata server MUST NOT
> grant layouts and mandatory byte-range locks simultaneously.